# Delete lines contening string except other string is in this line in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I want to generate a sub-schema (even if it is imperfect) by deleting all the lines that only concern the batch

I tried to make a replacement in the file with

`sed -i -e '/batch/!b' -e '{/web/!d;}' $target_file`

the output file should no longer have a line with 'batch' unless in addition to batch it has 'web' on the same line.

the problem is that the lines containing just web have also disappeared!

starting file:

```
  graph TD;
  
  classDef batch          fill:#050
  classDef web             fill:#005
  classDef batch_web       fill:#055

  classDef batch_livré    fill:#050,color:#0a0
  classDef web_livré       fill:#005,color:#0a0
  classDef batch_web_livré fill:#055,color:#0a0
  
  classDef conf_batch    stroke:#090,stroke-width:2px;
  classDef conf_web       stroke:#00f,stroke-width:2px;
  classDef conf_batch_web stroke:#099,stroke-width:2px;

  classDef batch_conf             fill:#050,stroke:#090,stroke-width:2px;
  classDef web_conf                fill:#005,stroke:#00f,stroke-width:2px;

  classDef batch_web_conf_batch    fill:#055,stroke:#090,stroke-width:2px;
  classDef batch_web_conf_web       fill:#055,stroke:#00f,stroke-width:2px;
  classDef batch_web_conf_batch_web fill:#055,stroke:#099,stroke-width:2px;
  classDef batch_web_conf          fill:#055,stroke:#099,stroke-width:2px;
  
  classDef batch_conf_livré    fill:#050,color:#0a0,stroke:#090,stroke-width:2px;
  classDef web_conf_livré       fill:#005,color:#0a0,stroke:#00f,stroke-width:2px;
  
  classDef batch_web_conf_batch_livré    fill:#055,color:#0a0,stroke:#090,stroke-width:2px;
  classDef batch_web_conf_web_livré       fill:#055,color:#0a0,stroke:#00f,stroke-width:2px;
  classDef batch_web_conf_batch_web_livré fill:#055,color:#0a0,stroke:#099,stroke-width:2px;
  classDef batch_web_conf_livré          fill:#055,color:#0a0,stroke:#099,stroke-width:2px;

  classDef livré color:#0a0;
  classDef mep color:#0a0,stroke:#090;

  subgraph Légende
    batch:::batch
    web:::web
    batch_web[batch et web]:::batch_web
    conf_batch[conf batch]:::conf_batch
    conf_web[conf web]:::conf_web
    conf_batch_web[conf batch et web]:::conf_batch_web
    livré:::livré
  end

  subgraph Jasslounge
    22.6.90.01.0:::web_conf_livré
    22.6.90.01.0===22.6.90.02.0:::batch_conf_livré
    22.6.90.02.0===22.6.90.03.0:::batch_livré
    22.6.90.03.0===22.6.90.05.0:::web_livré
    22.6.90.05.0===22.6.90.06.0:::batch_livré
    22.6.90.06.0===22.6.90.07.0:::batch_web_livré
    22.6.90.07.0===22.6.90.08.0:::web_conf_livré
    22.6.90.08.0===22.6.90.09.0:::web_conf_livré
    22.6.90.09.0===22.6.90.10.0:::batch_web_conf_web_livré
  end
  class Jasslounge mep
```

Desired output file:

```
graph TD;
  
  classDef web             fill:#005
  classDef batch_web       fill:#055

  classDef web_livré       fill:#005,color:#0a0
  classDef batch_web_livré fill:#055,color:#0a0
  
  classDef conf_web       stroke:#00f,stroke-width:2px;
  classDef conf_batch_web stroke:#099,stroke-width:2px;

  classDef web_conf                fill:#005,stroke:#00f,stroke-width:2px;

  classDef batch_web_conf_batch    fill:#055,stroke:#090,stroke-width:2px;
  classDef batch_web_conf_web       fill:#055,stroke:#00f,stroke-width:2px;
  classDef batch_web_conf_batch_web fill:#055,stroke:#099,stroke-width:2px;
  classDef batch_web_conf          fill:#055,stroke:#099,stroke-width:2px;
  
  classDef web_conf_livré       fill:#005,color:#0a0,stroke:#00f,stroke-width:2px;
  
  classDef batch_web_conf_batch_livré    fill:#055,color:#0a0,stroke:#090,stroke-width:2px;
  classDef batch_web_conf_web_livré       fill:#055,color:#0a0,stroke:#00f,stroke-width:2px;
  classDef batch_web_conf_batch_web_livré fill:#055,color:#0a0,stroke:#099,stroke-width:2px;
  classDef batch_web_conf_livré          fill:#055,color:#0a0,stroke:#099,stroke-width:2px;

  classDef livré color:#0a0;
  classDef mep color:#0a0,stroke:#090;

  subgraph Légende
    web:::web
    batch_web[batch et web]:::batch_web
    conf_web[conf web]:::conf_web
    conf_batch_web[conf batch et web]:::conf_batch_web
    livré:::livré
  end

  subgraph Jasslounge
    22.6.90.01.0:::web_conf_livré
    22.6.90.03.0===22.6.90.05.0:::web_livré
    22.6.90.06.0===22.6.90.07.0:::batch_web_livré
    22.6.90.07.0===22.6.90.08.0:::web_conf_livré
    22.6.90.08.0===22.6.90.09.0:::web_conf_livré
    22.6.90.09.0===22.6.90.10.0:::batch_web_conf_web_livré
  end
  class Jasslounge mep
```

thank you in advance

Comment: (1) How is the output supposed to look like? (2) In your example, the word _batch_ always occurs earlier than the word _web_. Can it also be the other way around, i.e. `classDef webbatch`?

Comment: I edit my firest post.
Indeed there is never a web before batch, but it's a coincidence and I'm also going to do the opposite command: a file should no longer have a line with 'web' unless in addition to web it has 'batch' on the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, then

```
sed '/web/! { /batch/d; }' "$target_file"
```

deletes all lines that contain `batch` but don't contain `web`.

The way this works is

```
   /web/! {      # in all lines that don't contain web
     /batch/ {   # but do contain batch
       d;        # delete
     }
   }
```

This would be more straightfoward with awk, by the way, where you could write

```
awk '!/batch/ || /web/' "$target_file"
```

Comment: Thanks !  That's exactly what I wanted.  I tested awk (which I don't know too much) it works well too even if I don't understand how it does it^^

Comment: Awk is a bit like sed in that (by default) the code is applied line-wise and is organized in condition-instruction pairs. If just a condition is given (as in this case), the default action is to print the input line unchanged. So what this code does is to print all lines for which `!/batch/ || /web/` is true, that is: all lines that don't match the regex `batch` or do match the regex `web`. And since both regexes are plain strings, matching the regex just means containing the string.